# Why does Herb Sutter's monitor example take a 'T' rather than 'T&' or 'T&&'?

Tags: c++, constructor

At 40:30 in [C++ and Beyond 2012: Herb Sutter - C++ Concurrency](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism), Herb Sutter shows a monitor class based on his wrapper idiom:

```
template<typename T>
class monitor {
private:
   mutable T t;
   mutable std::mutex m;

public:
   monitor(T t_ = T{}) : t{t_} {}
   template<typename F>
   auto operator()(F f) const -> decltype(f(t))
   {
      std::lock_guard<mutex> _{m}; return f(t);
   }
}
```

Note the constructor accepts `T` rather than `T&` or `T&&`, and includes neither constructor. The use case I imagine is:

```
monitor<Foo> foo = Foo(...);
```

Which fails for lack of a move constructor.

Comment: Why do you think it fails? Have you tried to compile the code?

Comment: (perhaps surprisingly) taking objects by value is often more efficient than taking them by reference or pointer.

Comment: @SergeyA It fails as `montior` is not copyable or moveable.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d59102777eb66d5a

Comment: Michael you need to use it like `monitor<Foo> foo{Foo(...)};`

Comment: Cases like this, another reason for value semantics is you don't want to take a reference as all-too-often people will accidentally pass a reference to local data then return from the function ... [this is secondary to @einpoklum's second point though]

Answer (score 4):

The constructor in Sutter's example takes a `T` rather than a `T &` or `T&&` because value semantics are the default in C++, and:

- there's no particular reason to assume you want to move a `T` when constructing. (Sometimes, there might be - but apparently not in this talk).
- you definitely don't want to take a `T&` - that means others are going to access your monitored piece of data without going the the monitor, i.e without taking the lock, i.e. without serializing the accesses...

Answer (score 1):

Only Herb Sutter can really answer that question.

If I had to guess, I'd say his reasons are:

1. It had to fit on a slide.
2. Including a forwarding constructor and an in_place constructor would only serve to confuse the reader and detract from the point of demonstrating the monitor pattern.

If you need this code to support non-copyable and non-movable types, looking at how [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) implements support for them, might be helpful.

Namely, `std::optional` has two constructor overloads.

- One constructor overload takes a forwarding reference (i.e. `U&&`) and uses [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to construct the wrapped type. This adds support for non-copyable types.
- Another constructor overload takes a tag type, [`std::in_place`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place), and `forward`s all remaining arguments directly to the wrapped type's constructor.
  This serves to construct the wrapped type in place, so it never need be moved.

Here's some example code: https://godbolt.org/g/hWmcTA

```
#include <utility>
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
class monitor {
private:
   mutable T t;
   mutable std::mutex m;

public:
    monitor()
        : t{}
    { }

    template<typename Y>
    monitor(Y&& y)
        : t{std::forward<Y>(y)}
    { }

    template<typename... Args>
    monitor(std::in_place_t, Args&&... args)
        : t{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    { }

    template<typename F>
    auto operator()(F f) const -> decltype(f(t))
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _{m}; return f(t);
    }
};

// A non-movable type, just for testing.
struct NonMovable {
    NonMovable(int n = 0, double d = 0)
        : n_{n}, d_{d}
    { }

    NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = delete;
    NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = delete;
    NonMovable& operator=(const NonMovable&) = delete;
    NonMovable& operator=(NonMovable&&) = delete;

    private:
        int n_;
        double d_;
};

int main() {
    // Non-movable type.
    monitor<NonMovable> m4; //< Good. Uses default constructor.
    //monitor<NonMovable> m5{NonMovable{1, 2.2}};//< Bad! Forwarding constructor.
    monitor<NonMovable> m6{std::in_place, 1, 2.2};//< Good. In-place constructor.

    // And a movable type, just to make sure we didn't break anything.
    monitor<int> m1; //< Good. Uses default constructor.
    monitor<int> m2{1}; //< Good. Forwarding constructor.
    monitor<int> m3{std::in_place, 1}; //< Good. In-place constructor.
}
```